# User not authorised to perform action in AWS Systems Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, policy, aws-ssm

I am new to the AWS platform and am trying to do a project similar to what is described here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/build-a-serverless-twitter-reader-using-aws-fargate/

I am currently in Step 4:Store configuration information in AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store. 
When I go to Parameter Store in AWS System Manager I get an error saying:

> User:
>   arn:aws:sts::413511889088:assumed-role/vocstartsoft/user292978=pdas@connect.ust.hk
>   is not authorized to perform: resource-groups:ListGroups on resource:
>   arn:aws:resource-groups:us-east-1:413511889088:/groups-list with an
>   explicit deny

There is nothing else that displays here except the error. I am using an AWS educate account to do this. Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: you'll need to ask your account admin for permissions to access that service

Comment: @JohnB Who is supposed to be my account admin?

Comment: whoever made you that role which you are using.

Comment: Were you able to find a fix for this problem?

Comment: @BusyProgrammer check JohnB's comment

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work for me as I am on AWS educate, and I don't have a specific admin. Thanks anyways!